# SQL Query multiple sums and avarage of total

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get help with a combined SUM and AVG function.

I currently have a time tracking system where my database `'hour'` looks like this:

```
#USER_ID #HOURS #DATE
1        2      2018-01-01
1        1      2018-01-01
2        5      2018-01-01
1        3      2018-01-02
2        8      2018-01-02
2        1      2018-01-02
```

What I'd like to get in the output is this:

**Avarage hours of today (2018-01-01):** 4 HOURS

What I could do is this:

```
SELECT AVG(hours)
FROM hour h
WHERE h.date = CURDATE()
```

But that would give me another output that the one I want, since in my example USER_ID 1 have two inputs, 2 hours + 1 hours. Like this..

2 + 1 + 5
**AVG: 2,666666667**

3 + 5
**AVG: 4**

So, my query should need a sum of each user and then get the avarage.
How could I do something like this?

Best regards!

Comment: What is your expected output here?  If you have another question, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can calculate average by computing the total sum using `SUM(hours)` and then dividing it by the total unique users in the group, using [`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUM(h.hours) / COUNT(DISTINCT h.USER_ID) AS daily_average 
FROM hours AS h
WHERE h.date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you! 
I've got a follow up question, I will add it in the question above in a minute.

Comment: @nikoh It would better you ask other question.

Comment: @nikoh happy to help :) Do consider marking this as accepted answer and optionally upvote :), if it helped you. You may post a new followup question for it.

Comment: Sure, I'll ask it in another one :) Thanks for the help with this one! Will mark it as the solution in 2 minutes when the system allows me :)