# Sum user hours and get avarage, include users who haven't added any hours yet

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow up question to my previous one:
[SQL Query multiple sums and avarage of total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604822/sql-query-multiple-sums-and-avarage-of-total)

I got the previous question working with Madhur Bhaiya's answer:

```
SELECT SUM(h.hours) / COUNT(DISTINCT h.USER_ID) AS daily_average 
FROM hours AS h
WHERE h.date = CURDATE()
```

Though I realised that I have a follow up question which is:

In my hours table I have two users who have reported their time, though I'd like it to count on the avarage of all the users that exists.
The hours database looks like this:

```
   #USER_ID #HOURS #DATE
    1        2      2018-01-01
    1        1      2018-01-01
    2        5      2018-01-01
    1        3      2018-01-02
    2        8      2018-01-02
    2        1      2018-01-02
```

That information is in my 'users' database, which looks like this:

```
#USER_ID #USER_NAME
1        aaa
2        bbb
3        ccc
```

Any idéas on how to do this? I assume I'd have to join the tables `'hours'` and `'users'`?

The desired output will be (BASED ON 2018-01-01):

```
(HIDDEN INFO: USER 1 TOTAL = 3)
(HIDDEN INFO: USER 2 TOTAL = 5)
(HIDDEN INFO: USER 3 TOTAL = 0)
**AVARAGE: 2,666666667**
```

Comment: Shouldn't the total be 6 for User 1 ? What is the logic behind the total ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No,  since it's supposed to calculate by each day. So the output of user 1 total = 3 is based on the day 2018-01-01

Comment: Just join the tables using a `left join` with `user` table as your starting table. Calculate SUM. And I would suggest that you can later determine your average in the application code. It will be faster there, instead of complicating this query.

Comment: I am suggesting this because you need the sum values also in your display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(h.hours) / COUNT(DISTINCT u.USER_ID) AS daily_average 
FROM hours AS h
RIGHT JOIN users u ON h.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
WHERE h.date = CURDATE()
```

Your issue of not taking into account users that haven't recorded any hours is that they don't exist on the hours table, so using the count of distinct users on the hours table isn't what you are looking for.

If you join the users table you can get the count of all users in the system rather than ones that haven't recorded hours, this should get you your average for all users, not just the ones that have recorded hours.

Answer (score 2):

use left join

```
select SUM(h.hours) / COUNT(DISTINCT users.USER_ID) AS daily_averag
from users left join hours on users.USER_ID=hour.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` and to put the condition for hours in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(h.hours) / COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) as daily_average 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     hours h
     ON h.user_id = u.user_id and h.date = CURDATE();
```

The above is totally correct.  However, it might be more performant to just use a subquery on `users`:

```
SELECT SUM(h.hours) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) as daily_average 
FROM hours h
WHERE h.date = CURDATE();
```